# Developers account not working, but already verified

Tags: facebook, verification, account

Our team have an account created just last year(2014) and used it as a Developer's account and was able to create an app.
We have an in-game feature  that let users post on their facebook wall through our app. But for some reason, the users cannot post.
Our developer's account has been verified by following the steps on how to verify a facebook account.

On the other hand, I used a  "personal account" to create the same app and was able to do the in-game feature  that let users post on their facebook wall, without any problem .

We really want "Team Account" to be our official developers account.
What might be the problem or cause of this or what might be lacking in our "Team Account"?

Comment: There is nothing like Team account. All user accounts need to be personal and you can only have one.

Comment: sorry I think you misunderstood the term "Team account" we just call it that way, it's a normal account.  
we created that account last year(2014) and used it as a Developer's account, we were able to create an app using that account, but we are encountering problem on users posting on their fb wall through our app.

while on the other account, which is my personal account everything works fine.

we just wanted to know, why are we encountering problems on the newly created account, while my personal account works perfectly fine.

I'm thinking maybe it has issue with verification.

Comment: I created an app using my personal account ONLY to test if it will work. And it did. Then i used again the other account, and it didn't worked. Both account have the same settings, except ofcourse for the names of the apps. Has it something to do with the length of time of account's usage?

Comment: you are not allowed to have more than one user account. team accounts are not allowed, user profiles must be used by one specific user and his real name. just use your own user profile if it works.